# How to yield span value in Cypress, so it can be compared later

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I want to compare two different variables in Cypress, and expect them to be equal using:
`expect(var1).equal(var2)`, however I'm not able to properly gather span value from it, as in example of HTML below.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="cat-results">
      <a class="cat-results-url" title>
        <span>Title I want to compare</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

I want to get only *"Title I want to compare"* value, but when I define it in Cypress I get following error:

`<failure message="expected { Object (userInvocationStack, specWindow, ...) } to equal { Object (userInvocationStack, specWindow, ...) }" type="AssertionError"><![CDATA[AssertionError: expected { Object (userInvocationStack, specWindow, ...) } to equal { Object (userInvocationStack, specWindow, ...) }`

I know that error is probably caused by me not able to define span text properly, instead Cypress is yielding it in unexpected place, which expectantly causes an error.

**What I do is, define:**

`const var1 = cy.get('.cat-results-url').eq(0)`, same with var2, then compare.

Are you able to help with direct how to yield this span value properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this. Save the inner text in an alias and then later extract it and compare it with the element 2.

```js
cy.get('a.cat-results-url span').invoke('text').as('titleText')

cy.get('@titleText').then((titleText) => {
  cy.get('selector').should('have.text', titleText)
})
```

If you don't want to use alias then you can directly assert as well like this:

```js
cy.get('a.cat-results-url span')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text1) => {
    cy.get('element2')
      .invoke('text')
      .then((text2) => {
        expect(text1).equal(text2)
      })
  })
```